# How do I find the number of template arguments used to declare a class?

Tags: c++, boost

How can I retrieve the number of template arguments that were used to construct some class? To clarify what I'm after, let's say I have some class instance, `A a;`, and I run the following to get its name:

> ```
> boost::units::detail::demangle(typeid(decltype(a)).name())
> ```

Let's say the output of this call is `someNamespace::A<Arg1<A,B>,int,5,Arg2<C,D>>`. I want to find a way of reliably getting the number of arguments (ie. `4`), considering that the arguments themselves might have any number of levels of nested template arguments themselves (which I don't want to count - ie. I want to count `Arg1<A,B>` as a single argument), and that the arguments could be any mix of types and values.

I'm open to manual string-wrestling to get this done but my preference is a compact solution using `boost`/STL.

Any ideas?

Comment: @vsoftco I'm not aware of any way to detect the number of arguments with a regex, at least not considering that any number of nested arguments could be used to compose the individual arguments...

Comment: Why not just use your own template `template<class T> struct num_args; template<class... Args, template<class...> class X> struct num_args<X<Args...>> { static constexpr int value = sizeof...(Args); };`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 I'm not sure how I would implement this. Here is my attempt: http://ideone.com/3QAjlf. Basically I want to get the number of arguments to whatever type `Derived` is, in this case it's `A`.

Comment: @Arman replace `struct` by `class` in `template<class... Args, template<class...> struct X>`

Comment: @0x499602D2: That seems to work for *types*, but not for values. I've edited my question to include my attempt at this suggestion. Any ideas on how to make it work for mixed types/values?

Comment: @Arman I don't believe that's possible. Types and non-type template parameters are two different things that can't be referred to under the same construct. There's no kind of "parameter pack" that can represent a type and a non-type at the same time.

Comment: @0x499602D2 that's a shame. I guess it's back to string parsing...

Comment: It's a known issue and C++ will likely fix it in the future, but not sooner than 2017, at least as standardization goes.

Comment: @0x499602D2 nice, can you do this with 2 types instead of 1? What I mean is using `X<Args1...>` and `Y<Args2...>`. I am trying this code `template< template<class...> class X, template<class...> class Y, typename... Args1, typename... Args2> struct num_args<X<Args1...>, Y<Args2...> > { static constexpr int value = sizeof...(Args1) + sizeof...(Args2);};` but I get a compile error (too many template parameters, 2 instead of 1).

Comment: Ohhh, it works, I forgot to add the non-specialized `template <typename X, typename Y> struct num_args;`

Comment: @vsoftco The primary template should also take two types meaning it should be declared as `template<class, class> struct num_args;`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 yeah just figured it out :) thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take the string in your example (with whitespace for clarity):

```
someNamespace::A< Arg1<A,B>, int, 5, Arg2<C,D> >
```

You want to get "4" from this, because there are four top-level types in the template.  The most robust way is to think about it as a grammar.  We could use Boost Spirit (warning: very hard to get right, and deity help you if you have a compiler error).  We could use ANTLR or good old flex/bison to generate a parser for the little language.  If we did that we'd aim to generate an AST containing the four type children together as siblings (two of them containing their own children  and ).

But maybe a hand-written parser is easier.  From left to right you can keep a counter of how many angle-brackets you're inside of:

```
someNamespace::A< Arg1<A,B>, int, 5, Arg2<C,D> >
000000000000000011111122221111111111111112222110
```

Then it's just a matter of counting commas when the bracket count is 1:

```
someNamespace::A< Arg1<A,B>, int, 5, Arg2<C,D> >
000000000000000011111122221111111111111112222110
                           1    2  3
```

Of course you add one for the initial type.